# react native hardwareBackbutton cause minimize app from Android >= 10

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, back-button

I dont know how to describe the problem by codes, but my `hardwareBackbutton` work normally for android devices with OS < 10. Another cause minimize app.

With `pop()` function from navigation, it's work. Only problem with hardwareBackbutton.

I am using native stack:

```
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.71.8",


...


export const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
```

Here is the video I captured: [Video here](https://vimeo.com/851681998)

Comment: What happen when you press on the plus icon?
Did you open a modal view?

Comment: plusicon = navigation.navigate('newscreen'). not modal

Comment: I think without sharing a full example I won't be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found problem because `OnBackInvokedCallback` putted on AndroidManifest,
as doc here:

`This replaces Activity#onBackPressed(), Dialog#onBackPressed() and KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/window/OnBackInvokedCallback